# How can I make my code for Chudnovsky's Algorithm go faster (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math, pi

I wrote some code to calculate pi using the Chudnovsky algorithm.  My goal is to print 1,000,000 digits of pi accurately.  My code works thanks to some tweaking and prior help from SO.
Currently, my code is set up to run 100,000 iterations where each iteration makes the outputted value of pi more and more accurate.  I am guessing that 100,000 iterations is sufficient to accurately arrive at 1 million digits of pi.  My working code is below.

I am using the "high performance iterative" version of Chudnovsky's algorithm (see wiki here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm).
[image]

Currently, it takes my PC about 12 hours to get 11.8% of the way to doing 100,000 iterations.  That is, it took 12 hours to do 11,800 iterations.  Assuming that I cannot upgrade or change my PC, is there a way to somehow make my program run faster?  Here is my working code:

```
import math
from decimal import *


# Returns the factorial of n
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    memory = n    
    
    for i in range(1, n):
        memory *= i    
    return memory


# Setting up Sigma summation
_sum = 0


# Here, input desired # of digits for decimal precision.  I use 1 million.  
# Entering 1,000,000 for desired # of digits of pi means doing 100,000 iterations 
# (1,000,000 / 10 = 100,000)
# "+20" is to avoid rounding error
getcontext().prec = int(input("How many DECIMAL DIGITS of pi do you want?\n\n")) + 20
iterations = (getcontext().prec - 20) / 10
iterations = int(iterations)


# If you just want 1 digit of pi
if getcontext().prec == 2:
    pi = 3.1
else:
    # Starting iterations and setting pi precision
    getcontext().prec += 1

    # Chudnovsky's algo starts here
    for q in range(0, iterations):
        
        # Prints percentage every 0.1%, occasional error of 0.00000001
        if q % 100 == 0:
            try:
                print(str(q / iterations * 100) + "%")
            except:
                print("0%")
        
        # "Components" for the fraction
        a = factorial(6*q)
        b = (545140134*q) + 13591409       
        c = factorial(3*q)
        d = (factorial(q))**3
        e = (-262537412640768000)**q    
        
        # Numerator and denominator
        numerator = (a*b)
        denominator = (c*d*e)
        
        # Adding fraction to the sum
        _sum += Decimal(numerator) / Decimal(denominator)
    
    # Second fraction
    sq = Decimal(10005).sqrt()
    overPI = Decimal(426880 * sq)
    
    # Calculating pi
    pi = (overPI) * (Decimal(1 / _sum))
    # Deleting rounding error
    pi = Decimal(str(pi)[:-20])

# Writing pi to a file
file = open("pi.txt", "w")
file.write(str(pi))
file.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are repeating many, many multiplications by not saving previous results during calculation of those factorials. (3q)! is, after all, 3q \* (3q - 1) \* ... \* (q + 1) \* q!, and similarly for (6q!). And since you've computed (q-1)!, (3(q-1))!, and (6(q-1))! in the previous iteration you can also take advantage of those to avoid many multiplies. You can also have cancellation when dividing factorials. Combining these observations you should be able to drastically reduce the number of integer multiplications.

Comment: Similarly, (-262537412640768000)\*\*q is simply (-262537412640768000) \* (-262537412640768000)\*\*(q-1), i.e. just save the q'th power from the previous iteration and multiply it by -262537412640768000.

Comment: As already mentioned in the previous comments, rewrite your code in a way that it can reuse in previous iteration already calculated values. This will turn multiplication into addition, exponentiation into multiplication and, to provide an example,  `factorial(q)**3` into multiplication `lastIterationFactorialExp3Value*(q**3)`.

Comment: Actually, the link **you provided** shows you the optimizations, so why haven't you implemented them?

Comment: I honestly don't understand the optimizations provided in the link.

Comment: But I do understand yours and Claudio's previous comments and will try doing them, thank you!

Comment: If you want speed ... pure Python code can't never ever beat the speed of a specialized Python module written in C or assembler. If you want 1_000_000 Pi digits in a fraction of a second: `from mpmath import mp` , 
`mp.dps = 1_000_000  # set number of digits`,  `Pi = mp.pi`. I suppose that the time of conversion of Pi to a string with its decimal representation takes more time than the calculation of Pi itself ... check it out and let us know. You can then look into the source code of pi method in mpmath to see how it is done.

Comment: Do you understand why the Chudnovsky algorithm gives Pi value? You don't need to understand the optimizations to write the code calculating the next term from the values obtained from the previous term. Take a look at `mpmath-1.2.0/mpmath/libmp/libelefun.py` code in the mpmath module. If i see it right, it uses another optimizations as these ones provided in Wikipedia.